# Get month from NSString, returning null value

Tags: ios, date, nsdateformatter

I am stuck at this from long time

`NSString *time = "2013/12/17 06:38:09 AM EST";` is a string and I want to get the `month` from it

```
 NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [df setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"];
 NSDate* b = [df dateFromString:time];
 [df setDateFormat:@"MM"];
 NSString* month = [df stringFromDate:b];
 NSLog(@"month = %@", month);
```

Comment: Replace
    `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm a"` in your code to:
    `"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a zzz"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not formatting the date properly, you are forgetting the seconds and the time zone

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss a zzz"]
```